# what is the fastest way to split a text file into multiple files using unique groups (of column values)

Tags: python, performance, split, group-by

I have a big data that needs to be split into multiple files as fast as possible.

If I have data like

```
chr    a_val    b_val   a_idx
2      1355     25d     abd
2      1785     25d     abd
2      1825     36g     ahj
3      1125     25d     abd
3      1568     25d     aky
3      2398     g67     abd
3      1125     25d     afd
3      1525     25d     abd
..............
.............
```

In pandas dataframe I would do.

```
my_df = pd.read_csv("my_file.txt", sep='\t')
my_df = my_df.groupby('chr')

# split the file
for chr_, data in gen_matrix_df:
    pd.Dataframe.to_csv(data, 'my_data' + str(chr_), sep = '\t', index = False)

# which give me multiple files by `chr_`
```

Pandas is very fast. But, would there be any other unix, linux or python based process to split the data in a fastest way.

Thanks,

Comment: Is `chr` always an integer and increasing?

Comment: Yes. Thats the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be faster because it doesn't pull the entire csv into memory, but you'll have to time it to see.

```
import itertools

with open('myfile.txt', 'rb') as in_fp:
    header = next(in_fp)
    for fchr, fileblock in itertools.groupby(in_fp, 
            lambda line: line.split(b'\t', 1)[0]):
        with open('outfile-' + fchr.decode('ascii'), 'wb') as out_fp:
            out_fp.write(header)
            out_fp.writelines(fileblock)
```